# Where are iWork templates saved?

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

I'm using iWork (specifically Pages 5.5.3) and I can't find the templates I created for this anywhere on the HD.

Library > Application Support > iWork > Pages > Templates > My Templates

Only shows the ones I've saved to that location. For some reason, I think because I do have iCloud enabled, it's saving it somewhere else, but can't find it anywhere related to iCloud either.

I've also chosen 'Show Package Contents' for the Application itself and navigated through the Pages 'Contents' folder with no results.

It's not related to iCloud. I just went to iCloud.com and tried to create a new document from the template chooser—my templates did not show up there.

It's because I selected the option to "Add To Template Chooser" as opposed to saving it to my HD. Where are these templates stored when selected that option? I need to edit the name of one and delete another.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Pages templates are located in the following folder:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Pages/Data/Library/Application Support/User Templates
```

You can rename and delete templates without accessing the folder directly, by right-clicking on a template in the template chooser.

[image]

Comment: oddly enough, I tried right clicking before posting. Still doesn't work though, might be a third party app, but the location is useful! thanks

Comment: That was strange. I had the View Option to show the Libraries checked but after I turned it off and then on again, the correct path showed up. I will move my templates to an external folder where I can sort them and convert them to useful Pages '09 versions that actually preview. Pages 5 can not divide My Templates into easily navigateable folders and they do not preview as raw templates. If I keep them locked in a standard Finder folder I can preview them using Quickview and rapidly open them in the version of Pages that actually works ie Pages '09.